# How to filter status with Rails Ransack's filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I found a description in the Ranksack tutorial (https://activerecord-hackery.github.io/ransack/getting-started/sorting) about filters. I have used Ransack to complete the search and sorting functions. I hope to add a filter to let the user select the desired state (this is one of the columns in the table) and point out the data that matches the state. But I don't know how to transform this code. Please give me some hints, thanks.

This is the code mentioned in the tutorial

```
<div class="filters" id="filtersSidebar">
  <header class="filters-header">
    <div class="filters-header-content">
      <h3>Filters</h3>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="filters-content">
    <%= search_form_for @q,
          class: 'form',
          url: articles_path,
          html: { autocomplete: 'off', autocapitalize: 'none' } do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title_cont, t('Filter_by_keyword') %>
        <%= f.search_field :title_cont %>
      </div>

      <%= render partial: 'filters/date_title_sort', locals: { f: f } %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :grade_level_gteq, t('Grade_level') %> >=
        <%= f.search_field :grade_level_gteq  %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :readability_gteq, t('Readability') %> >=
        <%= f.search_field :readability_gteq  %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <i><%= @articles.total_count %> articles</i>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <hr/>
        <div class="filters-header-content">
          <%= link_to request.path, class: 'form-link' do %>
            <i class="far fa-undo icon-l"></i><%= t('Clear_all') %>
          <% end %>

          <%= f.submit t('Filter'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      </div>    
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the current code of my page

```
<%= search_form_for(@query, url: list_tasks_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, t('search') %>
  <%= f.search_field :name_or_note_cont, placeholder: t('task_name') %>
  <%= f.select :status_eq, Task.statuses.map { |key, value| [t("checkpoint_status.#{key}"), value] }, prompt: t('all_status') %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<p class="lead"><%= t('task_list') %></p>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">
        <%= sort_link(@query, :name) do %>
          <%= t('task_name') %>
        <% end %>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <%= sort_link(@query, :status) do %>
          <%= t('task_status') %>
        <% end %>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <%= sort_link(@query, :priority) do %>
          <%= t('task_priority') %>
        <% end %>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <%= sort_link(@query, :created_at) do %>
          <%= t('task_created') %>
        <% end %>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <%= sort_link(@query, :due_date) do %>
          <%= t('task_ends') %>
        <% end %>
      </th>
      <th scope="col"><%= t('task_actions') %></th>
      <th colspan="2"></th>
      <th scope="col"><%= t('task_tag') %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row"><%= task.id %></th>
        <td>
          <%= task.name %>
        </td> 
        <td>
          <%= t("checkpoint_status.#{task.status}") %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= t("checkpoint_priority.#{task.priority}") %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= task.created_at.strftime("%b %d %R") %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= task.due_date.strftime("%b %d %R") %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('task_cont') , task_path(task) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('task_do_edit') , edit_task_path(task) %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= link_to t('task_do_kill') , task_path(task), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: t('task_do_sure') } %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= task.tag_list %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```